# GTM "dataLayer.push" is the only way to update the dataLayer from FrondEnd Developer?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I am so confused,
I let front-end developer put the GTM tracking script,
then I want to do "dataLayer.push" things,

Am I still need to talk front-end developer:
"please put this: [dataLayer.push(...)] code when the user clicked the buttons, thanks."

I am not sure GTM platform can push/update the dataLayer array or I still need to talk front-end developer to do this code...

thanks,
Terry

Answer (score 2):

There are [various triggers provided](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/topic/7679108) to you in GTM that won't require a developer to add additional code to the page.

For your specific example, you'll create a "click trigger" based on the CSS class (this is just one way of doing this) of the button and attach it to an GA Event tag with the event category, action and label you desire.